# Yandex карты не растягиваются на весь WebView в эмуляторе

Tags: android, html, yandex-maps-api, webview

Я хочу интегрировать в мое приложение Yandex карты, но столкнулся с такой проблемой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

WebView занимает весь экран (включая место под кнопкой), но карта не может раснятутся по всему WebView. Интересно еще и то, что в браузерах (и мобильных, и десктопных) и на реальных устройствах карта ведет себя как надо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код, отвечающий за WebView (MainActivity):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http://romhacking.pw/taxi_map/map.html");
}
```

HTML страница карты (*Я никогда не работал с JS прежде, так что код не блещет красотой*):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Быстрый старт. Размещение интерактивной карты на странице</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height, user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>


    <!-- Класс кнопки геолокации -->
    <script src="geolocation-button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ymaps.ready(init);

        function init(){
            var myPlacemark,
                myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                    center: [52.286387, 104.280660],
                    zoom: 15,
                    yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true,
                    controls: ['zoomControl', 'fullscreenControl']
                });

            //myMap.Container.enterFullscreen();

            // Создание кнопки определения местоположения
            var button = new GeolocationButton({
                data : {
                    image : 'wifi.png',
                    title : 'Определить местоположение'
                },
                geolocationOptions: {
                    enableHighAccuracy : true // Режим получения наиболее точных данных
                }
            }, {
                // Зададим опции для кнопки.
                selectOnClick: false
            });
            myMap.controls.add(button, { top : 5, left : 5 });

            myPlacemark = createPlacemark([52.286387, 104.280660]);
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
            getAddress([52.286387, 104.280660]);

            /*myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([52.286387, 104.280660], {
                hintContent: 'Иркутск!',
                balloonContent: 'Заебись'
            });
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);*/



            // Обработка события, возникающего при щелчке
            // левой кнопкой мыши в любой точке карты.
            // При возникновении такого события откроем балун.
            myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
                var coords = e.get('coords');

                // Если метка уже создана – просто передвигаем ее.
                if (myPlacemark) {
                    myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
                }
                // Если нет – создаем.
                else {
                    myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
                    // Слушаем событие окончания перетаскивания на метке.
                    myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
                        getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
                    });
                }

                getAddress(coords);
            });

            // Обработка события, возникающего при щелчке
            // правой кнопки мыши в любой точке карты.
            // При возникновении такого события покажем всплывающую подсказку
            // в точке щелчка.
            /*myMap.events.add('contextmenu', function (e) {
                myMap.hint.open(e.get('coords'), 'Кто-то щелкнул правой кнопкой');
            });

            // Скрываем хинт при открытии балуна.
            myMap.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {
                myMap.hint.close();
            });*/

            // Создание метки.
            function createPlacemark(coords) {
                return new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
                    iconCaption: 'поиск...'
                }, {
                    preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption',
                    draggable: false
                });
            }

            function getAddress(coords) {
                myPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
                ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
                    var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
                    // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
                    // Нужно сохранять город, чтобы передать его на сервер
                    var city = firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas()

                    myPlacemark.properties
                        .set({
                            // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.
                            iconCaption: [
                                // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
                                // Нужно сохранять город, чтобы передать его на сервер
                                //var city = firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                                // Получаем путь до топонима, если метод вернул null, запрашиваем наименование здания.
                                firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise() || firstGeoObject.getLocalities()[1],
                                firstGeoObject.getPremiseNumber()
                                // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
                                //firstGeoObject.getAddressLine()
                            ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
                            // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
                            balloonContent: firstGeoObject.getAddressLine()
                        });
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.apptrust.wingtaxi.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:text="Button"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Почему эмулятор не может растянуть карту на весь WebView? Это проблема эмулятора или просто неправильная HTML разметка?

Comment: Разметку с webview добавьте

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Добавил